# gevent not valid running Docker Registry

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am attempting to run a Docker registry on Ubuntu 14 using the following command:

```
sudo gunicorn --access-logfile - --debug -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 1 docker_registry.wsgi:application
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt this I get the following failure message:

```
Error: class uri 'gevent' invalid or not found:



[Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 139, in load_class

    mod = import_module('.'.join(components))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module

    __import__(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 24, in <module>

    from gevent.server import StreamServer

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 6, in <module>

    from gevent.socket import EWOULDBLOCK, socket

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 659, in <module>

    from gevent.ssl import sslwrap_simple as ssl, SSLError as sslerror, SSLSocket as SSLType

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 386, in <module>

    def get_server_certificate(addr, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv3, ca_certs=None):

NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3' is not defined
```

I did some searching and discovered something that told me to install python-gevent in order to get the gevent:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gevent
```

I did this and a subsequent invocation of dpkg:

```
dpkg -l|grep python
```

shows that python-gevent is installed.

Unfortunately, the install has not resolved the problem. I am still getting the same failure message saying that gevent isn't valid or found.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem??? Please advise...

Answer (score 4):

**re-Install python-gevent**

apt-get install python-gevent

pip install --upgrade gevent

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11886221)

Comment: @LaurIvan I think this is an attempt to answer the question, but it would be helpful if RaviBhure provided some explanation why this would work.

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting this in late 2022 or later, know that `gevent` versions 20.9.0 and earlier depend on `greenlet`, without specifying an upper bound on that version. `greenlet` has just released a breaking change in v2.x.x, and `gevent` doesn't work with it.

Pinning `greenlet=1.1.3` fixed it for me. More details about this issue here: https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/178

Answer (score 1):

try it:

1.find your python gevent package folder:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent
```

2.update ssl.py

from:

```
def get_server_certificate(addr, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv3, ca_certs=None):
```

to:

```
def get_server_certificate(addr, ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ca_certs=None):
```

3.try again:

```
$sudo gunicorn --access-logfile - --debug -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 1 docker_registry.wsgi:application
```